# Using Poliigon on object with multiple textures

Tags: textures, blender

This is my first time experimenting with Poliigon in Blender 3.6 and I was wondering if I'm able to use it on certain faces of an object. I'm making a chessboard for a class and we photoshopped the texture to make the checkers. The Poliigon is working on the bottom and side faces of the board but not the textures.

I tried looking up ways to add Poliigon to certain faces of an object and Poliigon on object with multiple textures and couldn't find anything to help.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If yes, please [edit] and add the relevant code as a [mcve]. If not, delete here and try [blender.se] instead.